# Understanding some postgresql.conf settings I changed

Tags: python, postgresql

I followed a Youtube video by Chris Pettus called PostgreSQL Proficiency for Python People to edit some of my postgres.conf settings.

My server has 28 gigs of RAM and prior to making the changes, my system memory was averaging around 3GB. Now it hovers around 10GB.

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 7GB
work_mem = 64mb
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
wal_buffers = 16mb
```

I am not having any issues right now, but I would like to understand the pros and cons of the changes I made. I assume that there must be some tangible benefits of tripling the average memory being used in my system (measured with Datadog).

My server is used to perform ETL (Airflow) and hosts the database. Airflow has a lot of connections but typically the files are pretty small (a few mb) which are processed with pandas, compared with the database to find new rows, and then loaded.

Comment: What were your previous settings?

Comment: See [Server Configuration](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config.html), especially [Resource Consumption](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-resource.html)

Comment: Just the default 9.6 settings. I never touched the conf file other than the hba one to allow certain connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shared buffers are used for postgres memory cache (at a lower level closer to postgres as compared to OS cache). Setting it to 7gb means that pg will cache to 7gb of data. So if you are doing a lot of full table scans or (recursive) CTEs that may improve performance. Note that `postgres` master process will allocate this entire amount at database startup, which is why you are seeing your OS use 10GB of ram now.

`work_mem` is memory used for sorts and *each* concurrent sort allocates a bucket of this size. Therefore this is only bounded by `max_connections` * concurrent sorts, so effectively it is *only* bounded by the sort complexity of your queries, so increasing this poses the most risk to system stability. (That is, if you have a single query that the query planner executes with 8 merge sorts, you will use 8*`work_mem` every time the query is executed).

`maintenance_work_mem` is the memory used by `VACUUM` and friends (including `ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY`! Increasing this may increase VACUUM speed.

`wal_buffers` has no benefit beyond 16MB, which is the largest WAL chunk the server will write at one time. This can help with slow write i/o.

See also: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: Note that your OS cache will also be crucial if you are dealing with a lot of TOAST-able (`varlena`) data types like `text`-containing rows that exceed 8K (the pg  page size), since while the _pointers_ to the TOASTed attribute values may be cached in `shared_buffers`, the actual value may be stored in a separate file. (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html)